# Setting values of a matrix equal to a function of their indices in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I'm very new to MATLAB so I am not fully aware of all the tips and tricks available in the language. I am trying to create a matrix of values equal to a function of their indicies, I have tackled this in my usual approach, but I feel there may be a much faster way of doing this. Thanks

```
outputArray = zeros(rowCount, columnCount);
for i = 1:rowCount
    iComp = ((i - (rowCount / 2) * constPWM / rowCount)^2);
    for j = 1:columnCount
        jComp = ((j - (columnCount/ 2) * constPWM / columnCount)^2);
        outputArray(i,j) = iComp + jComp;
```

Comment: Remember to always add a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use vectorization:

```
[ii,jj]=meshgrid(1:rowCount,1:columnCount);

outputArray= ((ii - (rowCount / 2) * constPWM / rowCount)^2)+...
             ((jj - (columnCount/ 2) * constPWM / columnCount)^2);
```